# .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to change URLs like below:

> http://www.gsmsite.nl/zakelijk/product/phone?b=met-internet-250plus

To:

> http://www.gsmsite.nl/zakelijk/product/phone?bundel=met-internet-250plus

How would I do that with an `.htaccess` rewrite rule?

Comment: Are you sure? _Both_ of those return 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a `RewriteCond` against the `QUERY_STRING` variable.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^b=(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/zakelijk/product/phone$  /zakelijk/product/phone?bundel=%1  [NC,L,R=301]
```

It might be wiser to do any business-logic redirects in PHP; rather than, complicating HTTPD behavior.

```php
if (isset($_GET['b'])) {
  location($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?bundel='.$_GET['b']);
  exit;
}
```